# closure of ball in metric topology(usual)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be  a metric space with metric usual topology $\tau$ Let $x\in X$ and $r>0$ then prove that $cl(S_r(x))=\{y\in X, d(x,y)\le r\}$ $cl(X)=$closure of X

---

$\{y\in X, d(x,y)\le r\}$ is closed set but how can we prove the equality ???//

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since it is not true (in general). If, say, $X=\{0,1\}$, with its usual distance, then $\overline{S_1(1)}=\{1\}$, but $\{x\in X\mid d(x,1)\leqslant1\}=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: when $d$ is usual metric ...

Comment: And I *did* use the usual metric. Therefore, I fail to understand your comment.

Comment: no sir i want to say in $X=\mathbb{R}$ and d is euclidean  metric ...but i get my answer...